# No environment variables in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

I have created a new OpenShift account for a new application I'm developing.
I have added a MongoDB cartridge for the database, and a Tomcat cartridge for the Java web application.

I now need to connect to the database from my Java web app, but I miss two authentication details:

- $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST
- $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT

As far as I know, I have to type `rhc env list -a the_name_of_my_app` in the console, but my application seems to have no environment variables set.
What can I do?

Comment: The website was the place to look: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html

Comment: That page suggest to use `rhc env list -a <appname>`. When I do the same, I get an empty list.

Comment: At any rate try conacting OpenShift support. You likely have a configuration issue with your setup. StackOverflow is not the best place to ask this question. Or, look at the "second" result from my google search: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399310-How-to-create-and-use-environment-variables-on-the-server-

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the default enironment variables are visible only via ssh.
In order to see them, you have to type `rhc ssh <appid-as-seen-on-openshift-console>` followeb by `env`.

Answer (score 0):

you can see environment variables by doing ssh to openshift. Also you can use openshift port forwarding feature to setup a connection locally to your database.
[Openshift blog link for port forwarding](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift/)